# Problem targetting only specified element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been working on a small jQuery plugin that creates an iPhoto-like preview when hovering over images. It all works great if I only have one set of images. As soon as I add more than one .preview set to the markup my plugin finds all of them and displays the total amount of indicators below each image.

Here is the JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // launch preview browser
    $('.preview').previewBrowser();
});

(function($) {
    $.fn.previewBrowser = function() {
        return this.each(function() {
            // get dom
            var $viewport = $(this).css('overflow', 'hidden'),
                $container = $viewport.children('ul'),
                $items = $container.children('li'),
                $single = $items.filter(':first');

            // set viewport to correct size
            $viewport.css({ height: $single.height(), width: $single.width() });

            // set container to correct width
            $container.css({ height: $single.height(), width: $items.length * $single.width() });

            // float items
            $items.css({ float: 'left' });

            // add indicator to dom
            var indicator = '';

            for (i = 0; i < $items.length; i++) {
                indicator += '<li class="left">O</li>';
            }

            $(indicator).appendTo('.indicator');

            // set default indicator
            $('.indicator li:eq(0)').css('color', 'red');

            // set scrolling position while mouseover
            $viewport.bind('mousemove.previewBrowser', function(evt) {
                x = evt.pageX - this.offsetLeft;

                offset = Math.floor(x / ($single.width() / $items.length)) * $single.width();

                $(this).animate({ scrollLeft: offset }, 1);

                // get current item
                currentItem = (offset / $single.width());

                // set current color
                $('.indicator li').not('.indicators li:eq(' + currentItem + ')').css('color', 'black');
                $('.indicator li:eq(' + currentItem + ')').css('color', 'red');

                return false;
            });

            // set default image on mouseout
            $viewport.bind('mouseleave.previewBrowser', function(evt) {
                $(this).animate({ scrollLeft: 0 }, 1);

                // set current color
                $('.indicator li').not('.indicator li:eq(0)').css('color', 'black');
                $('.indicator li:eq(0)').css('color', 'red');
            });
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

And here is the markup:

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="entry">
        <div class="preview">
            <ul class="container">
                <li><img height="350" src="images/digitalsamba_1.png" width="800" /></li>

                <li><img height="350" src="images/digitalsamba_2.png" width="800" /></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- end preview -->

        <div class="description">
            <div class="caption">
                <h2>CloudApp</h2>

                <p>
                    <strong>Product:</strong> CloudApp / <strong>Type:</strong> Development, Icon, Interface
                </p>
            </div><!-- end caption -->

            <div>
                <ul class="indicator"></ul>
            </div><!-- end indicator -->
        </div><!-- end description -->
    </div><!-- end entry -->

    <div class="entry no_border">
        <div class="preview">
            <ul class="container">
                <li><img height="350" src="images/digitalsamba_1.png" width="800" /></li>

                <li><img height="350" src="images/digitalsamba_2.png" width="800" /></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- end preview -->

        <div class="description">
            <div class="caption">
                <h2>Canon Lense</h2>

                <p>
                    <strong>Product:</strong> Canon / <strong>Type:</strong> Icon
                </p>
            </div><!-- end caption -->

            <div class="indicator"></div><!-- end indicator -->
        </div><!-- end description -->
    </div><!-- end entry -->
</div><!-- end content -->
```

I know I am targeting the items wrong but I just can't figure out how to do it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should take a look at [this tutorial](http://blog.virgentech.com/2009/06/building-object-oriented-jquery-plugin.html) describing OO jQuery plugins. The problem with your plugin is that it is just running on one 'set', not creating a new object for each set.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // launch preview browser
    $(".entry .preview").each(function(){
       $(this).previewBrowser();
    });
});
```

This will iterate through all `div.preview` in `div.container` and apply the `previewBrowser` individually